# Lambda treating null as false in bool where clause

Tags: c#

I have the following Entity Framework lambda query:

```
public IList<MyClass> GetMyClass(int id, bool show)
{
    using (var ctx = new DbContext())
    {
        return ctx.MyClasses.Where(x =>
               x.Id == id &&                      
               x.Show == show // <-- nullable bool
               .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreationDate).Take(100).ToList();
    }
}
```

My front end view has passed the `show` boolean down indicating the users preference for what to return.

In the database, the `show` property is `nullable`.

This is a very heavy query, so I have limited it to 100 at a time, thousands of rows are `null`, thousands are `true` and thousands are `false`.

**Question**

How can I say, without making the query inefficient, psuedo code:

```
.Where(x => x.Show == show) (where null or false == false)
```

As it stands, if I pass `False` down, the nulls are excluded, and I need them to be classed as False.

**I cannot change the database**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

how about

```
(x.Show ?? false) == show
```

Comment: It's the best C# code we can write but it translates to ugly CASE statement. I did a search and found no way to COALESCE.

Comment: I want to do " x.Show.GetValueOrDefault() == show " but it wont complile

Answer (score 4):

The following code should return records with Show == True when `show == true`, and records with Show == False or NULL when `show == false`

```
private void Repeat(object state)
{
    public IList<MyClass> GetMyClass(int id, bool show)
    {
        using (var ctx = new DbContext())
        {
            return ctx.MyClasses.Where(x =>
                   x.Id == id &&
                   (x.Show == show || !show && x.Show == null)
                   .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreationDate).Take(100).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another way to think about the expression. Not a good practice in LINQ to Entity.

```
(x.Show == true) == show
```